# Is it possible to treat text as xml element with lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'd like to filter an element tree to remove duplicate element entry. In short, I'm trying to clean an xml output to something that can be parsed by a different tool.

For example

```
<p>
  <p>
    Text node 1
    <ul>
      <li>asdasd</li>
    </ul>  
    <p>
      Text node 2 <span>Som text</span>
    </p>
    Text node 3
  </p>
  <p>Text node 4</p>
</p>
```

Would be converted to this:

```
<p>
  Text node 1
  <ul>
  <li>asdasd</li>
  </ul>
</p>
<p>Text node 2 <span>Som text</span></p>
<p>Text node 3</p>
<p>Text node 4</p>
```

In lxml, `getchildren` only seem to return xml Elements. So when I call getchildren on the `p` containing the `ul`. It will return a list  like `[ul, p]` thought, I'd want to have a list containing:

`[Text, Ul, P, Text]` So I can easily walk down or up the tree to reduce the superfluous elements.

Comment: I see in your question that you ask for `lxml` solution, but I can attempt to convert the example via `BeautifulSoup` if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of lxml suggests that they dont have a text node, and that text will either be part of that element accessed through the .text or will be  tail of a closing tag accessed through the .tail.

> `<html><body>Hello<br/>World</body></html>`
>
> Here, the `<br/>` tag is
>   surrounded by text. This is often referred to as document-style or
>   mixed-content XML. Elements support this through their tail property.
>   It contains the text that directly follows the element, up to the next
>   element in the XML tree.
>
> The two properties .text and .tail are enough to represent any text
>   content in an XML document. This way, the ElementTree API does not
>   require any special text nodes in addition to the Element class, that
>   tend to get in the way fairly often (as you might know from classic
>   DOM APIs).

I cant say the below is pretty or exactly what you want but might at least put you on a closer direction.

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.dat").getroot()
main_p = tree[0]
elements = [main_p.text]
for child in main_p:
    elements.append(child.tag)
    elements.append(child.tail)
    print(f"TAG: {child.tag} has tail: #{child.tail}#")

print(elements)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TAG: ul has tail: #
    #
TAG: p has tail: #
    Text node 3
  #
['\n    Text node 1\n    ', 'ul', '\n    ', 'p', '\n    Text node 3\n  ']
```

So "Text node 1" is the text of the main p. but "Text node 3" while its inside the main p is actually a tail tag of the inner p.

As an additional to this you can iterate over the main p elelment and if the child element is a p tag you can move it out of main p and add it in the root tag. again below is just an example.

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("test.dat").getroot()
main_p = tree[0]
elements = [main_p.text]
for child in main_p[::-1]:
    if child.tag == 'p':
        tree.insert(tree.index(main_p) + 1, child)
        new_p = etree.Element('p')
        new_p.text = child.tail
        tree.insert(tree.index(child)+1, new_p)
        child.tail = "\n"

tree.tag = 'something_else'
print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<something_else>
   <p>
      Text node 1
      <ul>
         <li>asdasd</li>
      </ul>
   </p>
   <p>
      Text node 2
      <span>Som text</span>
   </p>
   <p>Text node 3</p>
   <p>Text node 4</p>
</something_else>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I probably overlooked that. Kinda ugly to a tail text bound to a child node. When moving nodes around one could accidentally move text from within a child to somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree it seems a horrible design. I guess there must be some logic or reason behind it that's so clever neither of us can see it

Comment: Do consider XSLT as an alternative for this kind of transformation task. There's a learning curve, but once you've mastered the approach, it's much simpler than low-level procedural coding using a tree model.